# What to replace flex drain with

Tags: plumbing

Just bought a house with some questionable diy work.  What's best material to replace these drains with?  Abs?  [image: drain one][image: drain 2]

Comment: You'll get better advice by including a location; codes vary between PVC and ABS.

Comment: CA, thanks & sorry for not.including in original post!

Comment: Is CA California USA, Canada or Caledonia?

Comment: California, USA

Comment: Probably you'll be best off if you remove that 1st 45 degree elbow and connect the metal trap to the 1st straight pipe existing the wall.